# .htaccess RewriteRule Help (code provided)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file and would like to know how to rewrite /home to / (root directory)

I found the following code via another StackOverflow question:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Is this the correct code that I would use to rewrite the /home directory to appear as the root directory?

Comment: The rule in the question is redirecting all URIs that don't have `/home` to nobody knows where because you didn't include the requested URI, which is opposite of what you want, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect to folders outside of the document root. If you **really** plan to make the `/` of your box accessible via web, then you should create an apache alias named `/root` that points to `/` first. Add the following lines to your apache config :

```
Alias /root /
<Directory "/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then you should edit the .htaccess in your web servers root - maybe `/var/www/.htacess` - to something simple like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/(.*) root/$1
```

In addition you will have to make sure that the web server user has access to `/`

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```